# Create an EC2 instance for ruby on rails in AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Iam new to Amazone web services in Ec2.I created an instance in Ec2.I want to run a sample ruby on rails webpage in the created EC2 instance.How it is possible?? I just installed the `gem aws-sdk` only What are the remaining steps to do for running a rails web page in an EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Cloud Club, create an instance and install the rvm and ruby along with rails and other gems and packages which are required. Install your web server nginx or apache2. You dont have to install aws-sdk also.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk to deploy your Ruby on Rails app.  Amazon's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) on it is very thorough.